# PHP: Is there a way to print all the objects that have been created?

Tags: php

I'm working with Zend, and there are a lot of objects involved. Sometimes, I want to just print the objects because it dynamically sets so many setters and getters and various other things such as methods. It's kind of way for me to confirm that I am understanding it. Similar to var_dumping an array and seeing its structure, is there a way I can do this for objects of classes?

Comment: You can use the Reflection API to do things like get all the methods of a class, but to the extent that Zend Framework does things "dynamically" it's generally with things like `__call` and `__get`, which Reflection won't help with.

Comment: Sorry if I misused terminology. What was the better fitted word for "dynamically"?

Comment: I guess it's not so much the "dynamic" part that I thought of as poorly-chosen, it was saying that ZF dynamically sets methods. PHP (without some uncommon extensions) doesn't allow you to add methods to existing classes, it instead uses the "magic methods" which you can use to emulate that kind of behavior after a fashion. This means, even using some other functionality that allows you to list all the methods, you often aren't seeing the whole picture.

Comment: I see what you're saying for the most part. I guess it would be natural for me to ask, how can I see the whole picture then?

Comment: If you mean instantiated objects, you can use `get_defined_vars()` to retrieve a list of all variables that are in play, loop over that list and check each var for types, and then pick out only the ones that are objects.

Comment: @Marc B Wait, that doesn't work with instantiated classes and methods created from __set and __get righ?

Comment: if you mean you want to view what's been defined INSIDE a object, then yeah. but if you just want to see which objects got instantiated via `$x = new MyObj()` type stuff, then get_defined_vars will list those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of PHP 5, [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) can output an objects' properties in a similar fashion to displaying an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var_dump()` also for objects. It is not limited only to arrays.

Also you can use `print_r($obj)`. When working with HTML, to avoid having the output in one single line when printing the object/array you can type:

```
echo '<pre>print_r($obj, true)</pre>';
```

Alternatively in Zend Framework you can use `Zend_Debug::dump($obj, $label = null, $echo = true);`